# Multiple Ingress controllers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

We currently have at our company a Kubernetes cluster with an ingress controller that manages the traffic of the services and their endpoints.

We want to change our URL gradually, first add the new URL to point to the same services that are currently being used by the old URL, and once we see that everything works fine, we'll just make the old URL redirect to the new one.

That's the plan in a gist, however, I have no idea where to start. Do I add another ingress controller that is just copied from the one we currently have and update the SSL certificate to match the new URL?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of Ingress Controller (Nginx?) are you using and in what cloud environment?

Comment: I use nginx, with AWS

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've created your nginx ingress controller in it's own namespace? By default it's called `ingress-nginx`.

You can create your second Nginx Ingress controller in a seperate namespace so that it's logically isolated from your first. You'll need to give it a different name, but I see no reason why you can't do that.

Doing so will spin up a seperate AWS ELB, which you can then map to your new DNS record and then you can slowly migrate your services over.

Comment: Great, thanks, didn't know I could do that. I'll give it a try and update on that.